# Perform Load upon after click button

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, datagridview

I am trying to use the panel and buttons to load 2 different forms along with entity framework and ado model stuff. I am trying to load the 2nd form [this picture,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvRFs.png) using the codes running on the first form since they have the same table. but what happen is whenever I close the 2nd form and try to switch on the [second user from this form(driverlist), I am still getting the results that I created before on the first user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/412V7.png), I kinda think that the 2nd form is not being loaded although I put some code:

```
Private Sub DriverLicense_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim user_id As Integer = Driverlist.tbxUser_id.Text
    Driverlist.db = New [Emme_Subic_Transport_Corporation_Payroll].EmmeSubicEntities
    Driverlist.db.UserDetails.Where(Function(c) c.isDeleted <> 1 And c.Id = user_id).Load()
    UserDetailBindingSource.DataSource = Driverlist.db.UserDetails.Local

    If Driverlist.tbxUser_id.Text.Count < 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select an Employee ID First", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Drivertest.Panelswitch(Driverlist)
    Else
        Me.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DriverLicense_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
    Dim user_id As Integer = Driverlist.tbxUser_id.Text
    Driverlist.db = New [Emme_Subic_Transport_Corporation_Payroll].EmmeSubicEntities
    Driverlist.db.UserDetails.Where(Function(c) c.isDeleted <> 1 And c.Id = user_id).Load()
    UserDetailBindingSource.DataSource = Driverlist.db.UserDetails.Local

End Sub
```

I binded the 2nd form through other resources of data binding from the properties but still on the same resources as the first form. Im pretty new to this so please stop putting negatives on my questions. If you think I am bad at this, I know and I am sorry. by the way this is the code from the buttons and panel if that helps. Thanks everyone.

```
Sub Panelswitch(Panel As Form)
    PanelControl.Controls.Clear()
    Panel.TopLevel = False
    PanelControl.Controls.Add(Panel)
    Panel.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Btntest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btntest.Click
    Panelswitch(Driverlist)
End Sub

Private Sub Btntest2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btntest2.Click
    Panelswitch(DriverLicense)
End Sub
```

Comment: It is difficult to help you. Here is how you could improve your question. 1. Clearly identify which code goes with which form. 2. Either show or explain with comments in your code, what each variable, object, etc, is. 3. Describe clearly the wrong behavior, and what your expected correct behavior is.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of things I would avoid, just looking at your pictures, but that goes beyond your question.

Secondly, agreed with the comment, you should revise your question further (I see you tried, but still, it's neither complete or clear).

If I understand correctly, you have container `PanelControl`, which you fill *either* with a form `DriverList` or `DriverLicence`. I just want to make sure - are you sure you have your instances corectly set? Because I would expect that the switch would act only for *displaying* correct form, but should behave differently for the [persistent] list `DriverList` and `DriverLicence`, which *should* be probably a **new instance every time** you want to add a licence. But this code is not shown, just guessing the problem might be along those lines. There are quite few design possibilities, I guess.

Simplified, the point is:

```
Private Sub Btntest2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btntest2.Click
    Dim DriverLicenceInstance as new DriverLicence        
    Panelswitch(DriverLicenseInstance)
End Sub
```

I also think, that you might have your binding set incorrectly for the 2nd form, the `DriverLicence`. I'm not proficient in .NET binding, but it seems to me that you declare the bindings as two separate things (comes from the copying the code?). But what you probably need to do is to use the same binding source for both parts. See here: [A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial).